# How can I make 100 threads write numbers increasingly in a single file?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I know, I should use .join(). I am already using, but here is the thing: I make a round of threads (about 100) to perform some action, and after they complete, I start another 100 threads.

The context is that I am trying to check if x ports on my pc are open using threads. I start 100 threads and each check 100 different values and write their response into a txt file. The problem is that some of the ports are not being written to the file, while others are. When I run the code below, wanting to scan the ports from 3000 to 4000, I wanted my file to have 1000 lines, each specifying if the port is open or closed, but when I run it, it has, like, 930. Sometimes more, sometimes less, but never 1000 lines. Check below this code for another thing I tried.

```
def check_range_ports(ip_host, initial_port, final_port):
    threads = []
    count = initial_port
    loop = 0
    number_of_threads = 100

    while count < final_port:

        if count + number_of_threads > final_port:
            number_of_threads = final_port - count + 1

        for i in range(count, count + number_of_threads):
            t = threading.Thread(target=check_port, args=(ip_host, i))
            t.daemon = True
            threads.append(t)

        for i in range(number_of_threads):
            threads[i].start()

        for i in range(number_of_threads):
            threads[i].join()

        count += number_of_threads
        loop += 1
        threads = []

def check_port(ip_host, port):
    try:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
        my_socket.settimeout(5)
        result = my_socket.connect_ex((ip_host, port))
        with open("./ports.txt", "a+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            if result == 0:
                f.write(f"Port {port} is open.\n")
            else:
                f.write(f"Port {port} is closed.\n")
        my_socket.close()

    except socket.timeout:
        print("Timeout on socket!")
        sys.exit()

    except socket.gaierror:
        print("Error on the host!")
        sys.exit()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Exiting program!")
        sys.exit()
```

Here is another thing I tried. I created 10 threads, and each of these threads created 100 subthreads more, and each of these subthreads would write a line in a file. It works better than the previous, but I can't get 1000 lines exactly, which is what I am aiming.

What I'm thinking of doing is doable? If yes, how can I achieve it?

```
def start_threads(ip_host, initial_port, final_port):

    threads = []
    initial_port = 3000
    final_port = 4000
    number_of_ports_to_be_scanned = final_port - initial_port
    ip_host = 'XXX.XXX.X.XX'
    number_of_threads = 0

    if number_of_ports_to_be_scanned / 100 != 0:
        number_of_threads = int(number_of_ports_to_be_scanned / 100) + 1
    else:
        number_of_threads = number_of_ports_to_be_scanned / 100

    count = 0

    for i in range(number_of_threads):
        # if initial_port + count > final_port:
        #     number_of_threads = final_port - number_of_ports_to_be_scanned + 1

        t = threading.Thread(
            target=check_testing_port,
            args=(ip_host, initial_port + count, final_port)
        )
        # t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
        count += 100

    # for i in range(number_of_threads):
    #     threads[i].start()

    for i in range(number_of_threads):
        threads[i].join()

def check_testing_port(ip_host, port, final_port):

    sub_threads = []

    number_of_sub_threads = 100
    print(port)
    if port + 100 > final_port:
        number_of_sub_threads = port - final_port

    for i in range(port, port + number_of_sub_threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=check_port, args=(ip_host, i))
        # t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        sub_threads.append(t)

    # for i in range(number_of_sub_threads):
    #     sub_threads[i].start()

    for i in range(number_of_sub_threads):
        sub_threads[i].join()

def check_port(ip_host, port):
    with open("./testing_ports.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(f"Port {port}" + "\n")
```

Comment: This is completely unsynchronized. You're not protecting access to shared resources (like the file) in any way.

Comment: yup, I noticed that it is unsynchronized, hence the lines being completely out of order in the file. The lines missing in the file is perhaps due to two threads or more writing on the file at literally the same time (miliseconds or even smaller unities of time), or am I missing something?

Comment: I hope that you are merely doing any such thing as an *exercise* ... because you would never use threading in this way – let alone this number of them.

Comment: yes, absolutely, it is for school. I made a port scanner before but it was slow as hell, so I thought it was a good opportunity for learning threading.

Comment: You can e. g. use a "queue.Queue" where the worker threads put the results in and one dedicated thread gets the results and prints them.

Answer (score 2):

In `check_port` you wrote

```
        with open("ports.txt", "a+") as f:
                f.write(...)
```

That is insane.
In the sense that, it is a critical section and you're not holding a lock.

Acquire a mutex before messing with the file.

Or write thread-specific files, which
subsequently are combined into a single file.

Better yet, tell all threads to write to
a single [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), and have just one thread
read enqueued results and append them to a text file.

Comment: Hmm, does the `GIL` count as a lock that is being held, in this case?

Comment: No, it does not. You hold the GIL during open(), then release it. You reacquire it when testing against zero, then release it. You reacquire it during write(), then release it. You reacquire it during close(). That's not how a [critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section#Implementation_of_critical_sections) works. You need to hold a mutex for the whole thing.

Comment: I agree with you, a mutex is necessary for proper synchronization.  That said, I suspect that even in the questioner's unsynchronized multithreaded program, only one thread would be calling the C `fwrite()` function at any given time, due to the GIL.  So you'd likely end up with a file that has the data from each `fwrite()` call included as expected, albeit in arranged in an unpredictable order.  (contrast that to an equivalent multithreaded C program where thread A's `fwrite()` call could execute concurrently with thread B's `fwrite()` call and corrupt the output buffer)

Comment: I'm inclined to mostly agree with you. I suspect the file corruption stems from some interaction of chapter 3 printf() with chapter 2 write(). The printf fills a private buffer, and the write moves it down to a unified kernel view of the data being written. But I thought that trailing newline forces a chapter 2 write(), and it appears to me he usually has a trailing newline. (Scratches head.) Nonetheless, we _do_ observe corruption in the final output file. Maybe we have printf getting turned into multiple write calls, and they're interleaved across writers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly synchronise the access to the shared buffer you are writing to (the output file) concurrently. Only one thread at a time must write to the output file, otherwise you'll get a data race leading to the data corruption you observed.

You can ensure that only one thread is writing to the shared file by using a mutex, a queue or any other suitable concurrency primitive. Here is an example using a queue:

```py
import threading
import time
from queue import Queue


# Sentinel object to signal end of writing
__END = object()


def check_range_ports(ip_host: str):
    threads: list[threading.Thread] = []
    number_of_threads = 100
    queue = Queue()

    # Start the compute threads
    for i in range(number_of_threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=check_port, args=(ip_host, i, queue))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    # Start the writer thread
    tw = threading.Thread(target=writer, args=("output.txt", queue))
    tw.start()
    
    # Wait for all compute threads to finish
    for i in range(number_of_threads):
        threads[i].join()
    
    # Signal to the writer loop to end
    queue.put(__END)
    
    # Wait for the writer thread to finish
    tw.join()


def check_port(ip_host: str, port: int, queue: Queue):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    
    # Enqueue the result to teh synchronisation queue
    queue.put((ip_host, port))


def writer(filename: str, queue: Queue):
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        while True:
            item = queue.get()
            
            # End the write loop if there is no more item
            # to process
            if item is __END:
                break
            
            # This write operation is sequential and thread-safe
            ip_host, port = item
            f.write(f"Port {port} of host {ip_host} is open.\n")


def main():
    check_range_ports("127.0.0.1")
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```